# StripeException: No such payment_intent (Asp.net Core 6)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, stripe-payments

I am trying to refund an order from my admin user account and getting this error

> StripeException: No such payment_intent:

See this Controller Code:

[image]

Comment: Please put your code in the post itself. Not as image. Code present in image can't be copied if someone wants to try it and run it on his PC.

Answer (score 0):

"No such payment_intent" normally means Stripe can't find that Payment Intent on your account. There could be multiple reasons:

1. You specified an invalid Payment Intent Id (null/blank/typo)
2. You specified a Payment Intent that doesn't belong to your account

2 is a common mistake, especially if you are using Connect and specify some Payment Intent belongs to your Connected Account, but are calling from a Platform account, or the other way around. Best way to check is looking at your Stripe Dashboard request log: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs to locate the request, and use the search bar of your Stripe Dashboard trying to search directly for that Payment Intent

Comment: thank you, I think what you have mentioned in point 2 is what I have to deal with. but I'm logged in as a customer and paid for the order so the payment intent will be populated. in the other side (when I log in as admin) I am refunded the user by canceling his order so is that matter?